# How to do custom convolutional layer in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

In `Keras` I need a custom convolutional neural network, where input 6x6 and output 2x2. How to do this? ( Maybe with custom layer )

I have created numpy example ( bad and slow code ):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import image as mpimg, pyplot as plt
import json

def sigmoid(x, deriv=False):
    if deriv:
        return sigmoid(x)*(1-sigmoid(x))
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

def read_rect(arr, x, y, w, h):
    new_arr = np.zeros((w, h, arr.shape[2]))
    for pix_x in range(w):
        for pix_y in range(h):
            if x+pix_x >= arr.shape[0] or y+pix_y >= arr.shape[1] or x+pix_x < 0 or y+pix_y < 0:
                pass
            else:
                new_arr[pix_x, pix_y] = arr[x+pix_x, y+pix_y]
    return new_arr
    return arr[x:x+w, y:y+w]

def write_rect(arr, dat, x, y):
    new_arr = arr.copy()
    for pix_x in range(dat.shape[0]):
        for pix_y in range(dat.shape[1]):
            if x+pix_x >= new_arr.shape[0] or y+pix_y >= new_arr.shape[1]:
                pass
            else:
                new_arr[x+pix_x, y+pix_y] = dat[pix_x, pix_y]
    return new_arr

def size(l):
    l = np.array(l)
    r = 1
    for i in l.ravel():
        r *= i
    return r

class UpConv2D:
    def __init__(self, kernel_in = (10, 10, 3), kernel_out = (2, 2, 3), activation=sigmoid):
        self.kernel_in = kernel_in[:3]
        self.kernel_out = kernel_out[:3]
        self.weights = 2*np.random.random((size(self.kernel_in),size(self.kernel_out))) - 1
        self.activation = activation

    def do_pixel(self, inp):
        inp = inp.ravel()[:size(self.kernel_in)]
        out = self.activation(np.dot(inp,self.weights))
        return np.array(out.reshape(self.kernel_out))
    def call(self, inp):
        out = np.zeros(np.append(np.array(inp.shape[:2])*self.kernel_out[:2], self.kernel_out[2]))
        for x in range(inp.shape[0]):
            for y in range(inp.shape[1]):
                square_in = read_rect(inp, x-self.kernel_in[0]//2, y-self.kernel_in[1]//2, self.kernel_in[0], self.kernel_in[1])
                square_out = self.do_pixel(square_in)
                out = write_rect(out, square_out, x*self.kernel_out[0], y*self.kernel_out[1])
        return out
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.call(*args, **kwargs)

    def write_weights(self):
        return json.dumps(self.weights.tolist())
    def read_weights(self, data):
        self.weights = numpy.array(json.loads(data))
```

I need to make it for **Keras**. If kernel_out is (5, 6, 3) and inp is (100, 120, 3), then shape of output image will be (5x100, 6x120, 3) or (500, 720, 3). So I create empty ( zeros ) matrix with spae (500, 720, 3) and I fill that while scanning. Do_pixel is simple one layer neural network with input kernel_in and output kernel_out. Read_rect - get rectangle from image. Write_rect - write rectangle in image. It is something like upscale convolutional layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if input is 6x6 and ouptut should be 2x2, I believe you need simple convolution:

```
Conv2D(filter_num, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(3,3), padding='valid', activation='relu')
```

Do not forget that input is 4D as from [docs](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/):

> 4+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (channels, rows, cols) if data_format='channels_first' or 4+D tensor with shape: batch_shape + (rows, cols, channels) if data_format='channels_last'.

Comment: Output is 2x2 always, but input must be different ( 5x5, 6x6 or other ). So, how can I do it?

Comment: then you must create convolution for each possible input shape, as it can't adapt, and use the one you need, for 5x5 you can use 3,3 for kernel and 2,2 for strides